# Couchbase MapReduce performance

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

We have been doing development on a new project for several months on Couchbase and while we've done a number of views, we just recently introduced our first reduce.

The reduce function is operating on an index that is less than 100 rows, yet whenever I add a new document that matches the map, the reduce data is completely destroyed and returns zeros for all values. It stays like this for quite some time, 5 - 10 minutes, sometimes longer and then eventually starts outputting expected values.

Since the index is so small, I wonder what I might have done wrong. I could make it work with the data being stale - but going to 0 makes it unworkable. I'm hoping someone can look at my functions and tell me if I've written them in a way that won't perform.

The map:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.type == "json") {
    if(doc.object == "product") {
      emit([doc.account_id, doc.test], {active: doc.active, deleted: doc.deleted} );    
    }
  } 
}
```

The reduce:

```
function (keys, values) {
  var out = {active: 0, inactive: 0, deleted: 0};
   for(v in values) {
    if (values[v].active == true && values[v].deleted == false) {
      out.active++
        }
    if (values[v].active == false && values[v].deleted == false) {
      out.inactive++
        }
    if (values[v].deleted == true) {
      out.deleted++
        }      
  }
  return out;
}
```

We are running the latest version of Community edition - 2.2.0 (build-837). It's running in a dev environment with lots of hardware resources and very little usage. As a side note, other than this little snag, Couchbase has been great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the root cause of your problem, but you haven't handled the *re-reduce* case in your `reduce()` function - which can cause incorrect reduce results. See the Couchbase Developer Guide section on [Understanding Custom Reduces and Re-reduce](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-devguide-2.5/index.html#understanding-custom-reduces-and-re-reduce)

I'd also suggest temporarily removing the `reduce()` function to verify that the index operates as expected when when just using a `map()` function.

Comment: I checked my map output, and it was coming out as expected. I then worked on the rereduce and that *appears* to be the root of the issue. It is going to take me a bit more time to get it working correctly. In the meantime, however, I have opted to go with the built-in _count function vs. rolling my own solution. Thanks for the reference to custom reduces, that was very helpful.